# I am developing project using maven after giving correct name of servlet in servlet mapping, still not working giving classnotfound exception?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, mapping

[image: my project file in eclipse]

*This is loginpage.jsp file in which i am assigning servlet and method.*

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <%@ include file="navbar.jsp" %>
    <main class="d-flex align-items-center primary-background" style=height:70vh>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col=md-4 offset-md-4">
    
    
    <div class="card text-dark">
    <div class="card-header primary-background text-white text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
    <p>Login page</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="card-body">
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    </main>
    
    
    
    <!-- Javascript- -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is web.xml deployment descriptor in which servlet mapping takes place.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
    
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>RegisterServlet</display-name>

    <servlet-class>com.techblog.servlets.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.techblog.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is LoginServlet.java file in which coding part takes place. It is giving an error exception i.e.

> SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [LoginServlet]
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.techblog.servlets.LoginServlet

```java
package com.techblog.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.techblog.dao.Userdao;
import com.techblog.entities.User;
import com.techblog.helper.Connectionprovider;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        Userdao usd=new Userdao(Connectionprovider.getconnection());
        User u=usd.getbyEmailandpassword(email, password);
        if(u==null) {
            
            PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
            out.println("Invalid inputs");
        }
        else
        {
            HttpSession s= request.getSession();
            s.setAttribute("currentuser", u);
            response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you building and running your application?

Comment: I have created first connection with jdbc,then created register page then linked my register_jsp with my register servlet.Till here,the whole process is working fine,after inputting the field in register page it goes into the database.Then created login page,The login page also contains the same login_jsp  which I linked it to the login servlet as you can see the source code above.After running the application the register page is working fine but after entering details in the login page ,it is not able to find the login servlet class.

Comment: Your Java source files should be under src/main/java